# jqgrid total for grouping not for each page

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

I am using jqGrid grouping funcationality. And I have setup summary row.

That summary row shows up on each page , what I want is it should show summary after each grouping not for each page.

is there a parameter setting for that ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the summary row is providing the summary information for the the data that is displayed (as I'm sure you noticed).

You can:

- Display all the rows in the grid, which could be possible depending on the size of your data
- Calculate the values on the server, pass them via the `userData` parameter, and then overwrite the summary rows.  Note: This will mean you are loading in a larger data set on your server to perform calculations on it.

Comment: This was my escape plan if JqGrid does not have any option to do what I am looking for.

Comment: @user583726 Well unfortunately for you this is the case, and it only makes sense.  jqGrid can only summarize data for rows that it knows about, and when you are dealing with paged data you are going to run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can safely hide the footer row

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-sdiv").hide();
```

Comment: I know that. It does not work. I have edited the question with screen shots.

Comment: Please do not edit the answer you provided. If you want to change the answer you can comment here. If you edit, my answer will not make sense. It  will be confusing to user.